# Match elevation of permanent navigation drawer to appbar elevation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Consider the "permanent navigation drawer on desktop"
example on https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer#standard-drawer ([reference image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZhdU1LsJ3ARQE3uZfUQn_z7o5QWxtuk-FcRWKuXvvxkEAslRkLTk7tf4i82nxuFJWuPxLn7Y1dtskChk74U5axbm9zKRFdRSISMZhA=w1064-v0)). It shows a permanent navigation drawer to the side of the appbar. The Flutter implementation example uses a row widget to position the permanent drawer beside the Scaffold. However, if the appbar has any elevation, the shadow will cast over the drawer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdZlX.png) which doesn't look right.

Putting the drawer or its contents in a Material with the same elevation as the appbar doesn't work, maybe because the elevation doesn't carry over from outside the Scaffold?

How can I put the drawer at the same elevation as the appbar? (I would also like it to have a shadow over the rest of the content just like the appbar.)

Edit:

Code with Material at same elevation as appbar (I've also tried with removing the Drawer and putting the contents of the drawer directory under the Material):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF6200EE),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedDestination = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final textTheme = theme.textTheme;

    return Row(
      children: [
        Material(
            child: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Header',
                      style: textTheme.headline6,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 1,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    title: Text('Item 1'),
                    selected: _selectedDestination == 0,
                    onTap: () => selectDestination(0),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    title: Text('Item 2'),
                    selected: _selectedDestination == 1,
                    onTap: () => selectDestination(1),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.label),
                    title: Text('Item 3'),
                    selected: _selectedDestination == 2,
                    onTap: () => selectDestination(2),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    height: 1,
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Label',
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                    title: Text('Item A'),
                    selected: _selectedDestination == 3,
                    onTap: () => selectDestination(3),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            elevation: 16),
        VerticalDivider(
          width: 1,
          thickness: 1,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title), elevation: 16),
            body: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
              children: [
                Container(color: Colors.green),
                Container(color: Colors.blue),
                Container(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
                Container(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void selectDestination(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDestination = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, you can try to modify the elevation of the AppBar to be 0.0 And they will look flat, But if you want more control over it, I would suggest to create a new container with box-decoration and have the necessary changes. Also kindly post the code that you tried.

Comment: See my edit for code with the Material that I mentioned. I don't want to have 0 elevation for the AppBar; I know I could do that. If I add a box-decoration to the drawer, it will still have the AppBar shadow over it because it's still a lower elevation than the AppBar.

Comment: So I guess there's no proper way to do this?